# converting list elements(co-ordinates) to complex nummbers in python

Tags: python-2.7, complextype

co-ordinates of boundary are presented in list format, while conversion using,

```
result = [a[0]+a[1]*1j for a in c ]
```

where `c` is list containing co-ordinates. Above operation results in conversion but not in desired method. If `c = [[1,2] [3,4]]`,I want conversion as `(1+2*j)`, but it results as `(1+3*j)` i.e, it takes one one value from two different brackets, not perform conversion in same brackets.

Comment: If I run this I get the desired result. Note that you forgot a comma in your `c = ...`.

Comment: [[ 363.2  382. ]
 [ 363.2  381. ]
 [ 363.2  380. ]
 ..., 
 [ 362.2  383. ]
 [ 363.   382.2]
 [ 363.2  382. ]]
[[ 361.   382.8]
 [ 360.   382.8]
 [ 359.   382.8]
 ..., 
 [ 361.8  381. ]
 [ 361.8  382. ]
 [ 361.   382.8]]
[[  48.2  243. ]
 [  48.2  242. ]
 [  48.2  241. ]
 [  48.   240.8]
 [  47.2  240. ]
 [  47.2  239. ]
 [  47.2  238. ]
 [  47.   237.8]
 [  46.2  237. ]
 [  46.2  236. ]
 [  46.2  235. ]
 [  46.   234.8]

Comment: this is how my actually list appears....there is no comma in between them

Comment: Then it is not a list. What is the result of `type(c)`?

Comment: type(c) is 'list' only

Comment: how should i proceed??

Comment: well your problem seems not reproduceable right now. I propose you create a reproduceable problem (in the question) we can run and then debug.